# What would be pure energy ?An example of pure energy?

Tags: energy

Is electron a form of pure energy .
What would be pure energy,or what could be referred as the original form of energy. From where all things begin.Has this been found out. Or the universe is thought to exist just by itself??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is pure energy?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15122/)

Comment: Energy is defined as the ability to do work, and that is all it is.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy

Comment: I meant what could possibly the initial energy be  which gave rise to all there is and there shall be.

Comment: Pure energy can be the light because it has no mass.

Comment: @Energizer777 Nope. Not even close. Light is electric and magnetic fields. The basic problem with this kind of question is that "energy" isn't a thing, it's a property.

Comment: Any sort of radiation is pure energy,be it in form of heat or light or any other form

Comment: The quest is to find which energy is the source of all energies available.